# broken old release capistrano, how use new release?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I have created new releases with command:

```
cap deploy
```

I have deleted old release with:

```
cap deploy:cleanup -s keep_releases=1
```

My deploy.rb working fine is:

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path'])) # Add RVM's lib directory to the load pathe
require "rvm/capistrano"                  # Load RVM's capistrano plugin.
require "bundler/capistrano"
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.2-p318@global'  
set :rvm_type, :user
set :application, "mydomain.com"
set :user, 'user'
set :repository,  "#{user}@ip.ip.ip.ip:~/application"
set :scm, :git
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :keep_releases, 2
set :deploy_to, "~/#{application}"
role :web, "ip.ip.ip.ip"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "ip.ip.ip.ip"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "ip.ip.ip.ip", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
after "deploy:update", "deploy:cleanup"
```

When I try refresh my webpage I get this:

```
Errno::ENOENT

No such file or directory - /home/user/mydomain.com/releases/20120321181235/config/locales/devise.en.yml
```

The release `20120321181235` does not exist, this is a old release. I want to use the new release with changes in my files.

**How can I do this?**

Thank you

Comment: I think you would need at least do new deploy, list available releases, then do the cleanup and gist log of the cleanup, do you happen to have some LANG settings on server or anything that could affect sorting order ?

Comment: Thank you the problem was fixed. I have clean every releases and I have made a new deploy, and the problem was fixed. Thank you